# BuildTasks.csc not loaded in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, nuget

this question has been posted few times but the answers do nothing for me, here is what I get on compile:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

It worked before, now when I open it, I get this error.

I do not use a repository as some users suggest, I also restarted and cleaned the solution, deleting the nuget packages from the solution folder also does nothing.

Whats the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried Nuget Package Restore which comes on Solution level menu ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi your problem is that you are missing the reference to "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" file within your solution. If you have a backup of your project try and get the file from the previous backup in order to create the program executable again.

Comment: this is not a project level file, its a MS toolkit. User seem to be missing some package